# Creating custom global and class methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

What is the process called when we are creating our own methods to be used with a jQuery object (for example) like this:

```
$('#myobject').myMethod1().myMethod2();
```

How can we make it so that those methods works for jQuery objects and any others like a string?  I assume the Object keyword comes into play here.  Is it here that we use those prototype keywords?  They say it is bad practice to define your own prototype methods as you may redefine a built-in one, got it.  Just need to know how we can do it though rather then create a standard function like:

```
function myFunction(theObject) {
}
```

And finally, if we have a class, can we define our own methods to be used only inside that class?

```
class MyClass {
    static MyFunction() {
        "ABCDE".myClassMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: a) jQuery plugin b) `Object.prototype` c) yes.